# what is the solution for Crystal Report Filter option in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

i'm using asp.net/c# with crystal report to export as PDF format, it is exporting Pdf fine. but we refereed the DB Table to Crystal Report so it is binding all data's to report not filter by parameter or select Formula model.

> Here is My Code:

```
ReportDocument myreportdocument = new ReportDocument();
            DataSet dsReport = new DataSet();
            clsiCMSBLBase omenu = new clsiCMSBLBase();
            string errMsg = string.Empty;
            dsReport = omenu.GetListData(ref errMsg, parameters, "DBSP_PCPrintSlipRDLC");

            myreportdocument = ReportFactory.GetReport(myreportdocument.GetType());
            myreportdocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrysReports/PCPrintSlipPUD.rpt"));

            myreportdocument.SetParameterValue("UserID", Convert.ToInt32(2));
            myreportdocument.SetDataSource(dsReport);

            string dbUserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CrystalUserName"];
            string dbPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CrystalPassword"];
            myreportdocument.SetDatabaseLogon(dbUserName, dbPassword);

            cRY1.ReportSource = myreportdocument;
            cRY1.SelectionFormula = " {TMP_PlotPCSlip.UserID} =" + 2;
            cRY1.ReportSource = myreportdocument;
            cRY1.HasCrystalLogo = false;
            cRY1.DataBind();
            cRY1.RefreshReport();
            cRY1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            cRY1.BorderWidth = 1;
            cRY1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            cRY1.Style.Add("width", "100%");

            //string filename = fact + "_" + flag + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm") + ".pdf";
            myreportdocument.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, filename);
            Response.End();
```

> this Filter Code not filtering:

```
myreportdocument.SetParameterValue("UserID", Convert.ToInt32(2));
```

even i tried TableName.UserID but there is also not filter, so please share your experience..

Comment: check the cRY1.ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh property. Is it true?

Answer (score 0):

```
Myreportdocument.RecordSelectionFormula="{table.column}=2"
```